# Multi column select query

Tags: codeigniter

my table field are

```
payid   payamount   paytype
01      5000        1
02      3000        1
03      2500        3
```

I want to get result as  `select cash =(select sum (payamount)where paytype=1) 
online=(select sum (payamount)where paytype=2) 
check=(select sum (payamount)where paytype=3)`

how I can do it in codeigniter?

Comment: payid, payamount, paytype            value for three rows as follows                                                         . 01, 5000, 1.                                                                                               02 3000, 1,                                                                                                 03 2500, 3

Comment: explore your question in a good way...!

Answer (score 0):

may be you are looking for the following

```
$this->db->select("SUM(payment)")
        ->from("TABLE_NAME")
        ->where("paytype", $paytype)
```

put the TABLE_NAME and pass the $paytype and hope it will work...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a GROUP BY.

```
SELECT sum(paymount), paytype FROM mytable GROUP BY paytype;
```

In Codeigniter you can use

```
$this->db->select_sum('paymount');
$this->db->select('paytype');
$this->db->group_by('paytype');
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getincomebyyear($s,$e){
        $this->db->select('income_id, income_date,income_source,income_sourceid,income_refferanceid,income_description,income_amount,(select sum(income_amount) from tbl_incomes where income_description=1) as cash,'
                . '(select sum(income_amount) from tbl_incomes where income_description=2) as online,'
                . '(select sum(income_amount) from tbl_incomes where income_description=3) as che');
    $this->db->from('tbl_incomes');
        $this->db->where('income_date between'
                . ' "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($s)). '" and'
                . ' "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($e)).'"');
        $query_result= $this->db->get();
        $result=$query_result->result();
        return $result;
    }
```